Is there any restriction for locally mapping a given 2-qubit density matrix into a desired 2-qubit density matrix with lower entanglement?
Suppose we're given a 2-qubit density matrix($\rho_{4\times4}$). we can apply two local maps on each of these qubits seperatly. So the output is density matrix($\rho^{\prime}_{4\times4}$).
I'm wondering if we can find two sets of Kraus operators (two local maps and specific for the given $\rho$), transforming $\rho$ into the desired density matrix $\rho^{\prime}$ which has the form:
$$\rho^{\prime}=p|uv\rangle\langle uv|+(1-p)|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$$
where $|uv\rangle$ is seperable state and $|\phi\rangle$ is completely entangled state. also $\langle\phi|uv\rangle=0$

Is it even clear that the answer does not depend on how you define "lower"?

It doesn't matter how low the entanglement of the output will be (but should not be zero!); what matters is the structure of the output density matrix. For instance, the output density matrix should be a mixture of only two Bell states.

I think your question would profit from more detail.

I have revised my question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Thanks. Some arbitrary |u>, |v>, |phi> (which I can choose), or some given ones (which you choose beforehand)? -- Also, why the orthogonality condition?

A trivial answer to your question is to just discard the state and prepare |uv>. So you will have to be more specific.

yes,  |u>, |v>, |phi> are arbitrary. and the orthogonality condition is helpful for entanglement distillation of that density matrix.

Note that entanglement distillation might pose limits on what you can do (or what you can prove); there's lots of hard open problems as well as impossibility results.

I understand you. but what I'm saying is that if there's a possible way to make a density matrix(with specific form above and with minimum entanglement) out of a given density matrix, then It can be distilled in one step(and with probability P) into a completely entangled state.

Indeed. And this tells you that it will be very hard to say something smart about this, because a lot of smart people tried to solve distillability for a very long time and there is still big gaps in our understanding. (Also, are you sure that your claim about distillability is correct? I have doubts. In particular, if p>1/2, this state should be separable, I would think, at least if I think from a perspective of Bell-diagonal states.)

I completely agree with you. Regarding the last question, what I understand from your statement about (p>0.5) and separability , is that these states have a fully entangled fraction equal to zero (not concurrence). Therefore, they cannot be distilled using DEJMPS or BBPSSW protocols. However, this does not imply that they lack any entanglement. By utilizing the EPL (Extreme Photon Loss) protocol, a maximally entangled state with a probability of  0.5(1-p)^2  can be achieved from states with the form above.
